# Spirte jump after collision with other sprite

Tags: c++, box2d, cocos2d-x

After collision using listener one, `sprite1` should be destroyed and other `sprite2` will jump. I destroy `sprite1` but `sprite2` is not jumping after collision with sprite1.  Here is my code:

```
Update(float dt) {   
    if(collisionOccurs == 1)
    {
         CCJumpTo * myJump = CCJumpTo::create(1, ccp(winSize.width/6,winSize.height/8),winSize.height/2 ,1);
         Sprite2->runAction(myJump);

         collisionOccurs = 0;

         if(Sprite1 != NULL && BodyofSprite1 != NULL)
         {
             BodyofSprite1->SetActive(false);
             Sprite1->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
         }
    }
 }
```

Comment: You can not combine physics with move/rotate/follow actions. They are two inherently incompatible ways to change position and rotation of a node, and will cause conflicts or unexpected behavior. If you want the sprite to jump, change its body's velocity or apply an impulse.

Comment: I used the  linearimpulse. But body's speeed becomes so much high if i applied linearimpulse on body at a same time.Body goes away from screen. Thats my issue with LinearImpulse.So what should be more benefit for me ApplyLinearImpiulse or LinearVelocity?

Comment: I want a constant speed of body  and motion of body is limited in screen. How can it possible?? Any better idea?

Comment: impulse requires an opposite force (aka gravity) if you want the body to come down. Constant motion = set velocity for n frames to the same value if that's what you want. There's no alternative to moving physics bodies with physics force/impulse or direct changes to velocity. And yes, it involves a LOT of tweaking to get right.

Comment: Thank u.How can limited the moving area of body in screen?? Means body not goes updward more than screen's half height?

Comment: an edge-based body at the appropriate height or shape will do

Comment: Ok sir.. But sir thread comes in game sometime. This thread is out of my mind. why it comes? While now i am using SetLinearVelocity. The thread is                                                              inline bool b2World::IsLocked() const
{
    return (m_flags & e_locked) == e_locked;
}
i also asked a question with you. pleaser solve my problem.Thank You.